# How to handle Localization in a bundle?

Tags: android, localization, bundle

As per the current Android Bundle concept an app downloads the resource files dynamically based on the device configuration.
The one problem which I am facing is with Localisation. In my app users should be able to switch between multiple languages at any point of time using App Settings screen.
But since android bundle delivers the content dynamically so only one localisation file is getting downloaded on the device at any point of time. And the disadvantage of this is that when user is switching to a new language using App Settings screen that selected language is not getting reflected in the app. 
How to handle this kind of scenario where I want all language files to be available in the app irrespective of the user device configuration ?

Comment: Can anyone provide a solution for this ?